# A Device error come in when I start my Greenfoot software

Tags: javascript, java, windows, device, display

when I start my greenfoot software on my computer I am getting this message.

" Device "Intel(R) G41 Express Chipset (Microsoft Corporation - WDDM 1.1)" (\.\DISPLAY1) initialization failed : 
WARNING: bad driver version detected, device disabled. Please update your driver to at least version 8.15.10.2302 "

What does this mean? I am using a Dual core, 2GB RAM, Windows-7 Home Premium, operating system. When I click the new scenario link in my computer, my download folder comes into the screen instead of the new scenario window shown in their videos. Why? And there is error message that come when I open a scenario from my download folder.